# Scripting - Iterating Numbers Using a While Loop (newusers command)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos7

I am working on a script where I want to iterate between the numbers 1 to 15, but want it shown as 01 02 03 ... 13 14 15. Essentially what I am trying to do is add 15 users using the newusers command and using this script as < to the command. newusers needs to be in this format:

pw_name:pw_passwd:pw_uid:pw_gid:pw_gecos:pw_dir:pw_shell

Basically, it should look like this when I run the script with arguments =

```
cstuser01:EzVlK9Je8JvfQump:1001:1001:CST8177 user:/home/cstuser01:/bin/bash
cstuser02:EsKOfvhgnWpiBT6c:1002:1002:CST8177 user:/home/cstuser02:/bin/bash
cstuser03:qzQuR5vRgxdzY6dq:1003:1003:CST8177 user:/home/cstuser03:/bin/bash
```

I got most of it working but I am getting the error below:

> ./15users.sh: 57: ./15users.sh: Illegal number: 08

Here is my script so far (I took out a couple sections with error checking) =

```
#!/bin/sh -u
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin ; export PATH
umask=022

#num=1 (this variable is needed depending on which loop I use below)
user=$prefix"user"
uid=1001
gid=$uid
home=/home/$user
shell=/bin/bash

#echo "pw_name:pw_passwd:pw_uid:pw_gid:pw_gecos:pw_dir:pw_shell"
#PASSWD=$(openssl rand -base64 12)
```

I originally had this but ran into a few problems:

```
while [ $NUM -le 15 ] ; do
       if [ $NUM -lt 10 ] ; then
               NUM=0$NUM
       fi
       echo "$USER$NUM:$(openssl rand -base64 12):$UID:$GID:$GECO:$HOME$NUM:$SHELL"
       UID=$(( UID + 1 ))
       GID=$(( GID + 1 ))
       NUM=$(( NUM + 1 ))
done
```

A friend of mine suggested this, it works perfectly fine. But I am trying to future proof this thing. What if I have a 100 or 1,000 users to add.

```
for NUM in 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 ; do
       echo "$USER$NUM:$(openssl rand -base64 12):$UID:$GID:$GECO:$HOME$NUM:$SHELL"
done
```

This didn't work:

```
for num in {01..15} ; do
    i=09
    echo "$(( 10#$num + 1 ))"
    10
done
```

I then tried this getting a syntax error =

./15users.sh: 50: ./15users.sh: Syntax error: Bad for loop variable

```
for (( num=1; num<=15; num++ )) ; do
    printf "%02d\n" $num
done
```

I tried this as well but seq prints vertically not horizontally:

```
#iterate=$(seq -w 1 15)
for $iterate ; do
       echo "$user$num:$(openssl rand -base64 12):$uid:$gid:$geco:$home$num:$shell"
done
```

Answer (score 4):

1. To loop over 01 to 15, it is much simpler to use brace expansion:

   ```
   $ for num in {01..15}; do echo "$num"; done
   01
   02
   03
   04
   05
   06
   07
   08
   09
   10
   11
   12
   13
   14
   15
   ```
2. In bash, by default, numbers beginning with `0` are octal.  Since `08` and `09` are illegal as base-8 numbers, they will cause an error.  To avoid that, explicitly specify the base:

   ```
   $ i=09; echo $(( 10#$i + 1 ))
   10
   ```

   The expression `10#$i` tells bash to interpret `$i` as a base-10 number.
3. Do **NOT** use all caps for your script variables.  The system uses all caps and you don't want to accidentally overwrite a system variable.

   In the case of `UID`, it is a **read-only** bash variable.  Attempts by your script to assign `UID` will fail.  Use lower or mixed-case for your script variables.
4. Another example of the all caps problem is `$HOME`.  Note that the following code works:

   ```
   $ openssl rand -base64  12
   1bh9+dp+Ap7xFIBB
   ```

   But the following fails:

   ```
   $ (HOME=/home/user; openssl rand -base64  12)
   zceZeWsQGpohTPvv
   unable to write 'random state'
   ```

   Apparently, `openssl` expects to have write-access to `$HOME`. 
   Assigning `HOME` to a non-existent directory causes an error.

   So, again, *do not all all caps for your script variables.*

Answer (score 1):

I won't try to diagnose your error message, but you're over-complicating what you're trying to achieve.

```
for i in {01..15}; do echo $i; done
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

Comment: for num in {01..15} ; do
        num=01
        echo "$(( 10#$num + 1 ))"
        10
done

Comment: @Darren, can you please edit your original post and add the modified script?  It's hard to understand what you changed and in what way it's failing...

Comment: There you go, I added the changes above

Answer (score 1):

Bash supports C style loops as well:

```
$ for (( i=1; i<=15; i++ )); do printf "%02d\n" $i; done
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

Just use `printf` with the flag to print leading `0` and you have your output.

Comment: You seem to have omitted the semicolons in your code. This works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Since it hasn't been mentioned yet:

```
seq -w 1 15
```

```
seq -w 1 15 | while read num; do echo "n=$num"; done
```

Comment: how do I put this is a for loop